# Gmail API Python: Optimize code to send email faster

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

The code below works. I can send emails through the Gmail API, but it takes awhile to send 10 personalized emails, based on wall time (20-30 secs).  Is there a way to optimize the code below to send emails faster? There are quota limitations.

Is the max number emails one can send, a 100 per day?  There seems to be a difference between number of emails one can send and the number of receipts per email.  This is the documentation I am sourcing: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

I am using the consumer version.

Feature Consumer (gmail.com)
Calendar events created 5,000
Contacts created    1,000

Documents created   250

Email recipients per day    100*

Code:

```
import httplib2
import os
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client, tools
import base64
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from apiclient import errors, discovery
import mimetypes

import pandas as pd
import textwrap

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'AppName'

def get_credentials():
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'gmail-send.json')
    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
        print 'Storing credentials to ' + credential_path
    return credentials

def SendMessage(sender, to, subject,message_text):
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    message1 = CreateMessageHtml(sender, to, subject, message_text)
    result = SendMessageInternal(service, "me", message1)
    return result

def CreateMessageHtml(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    msg = MIMEText(message_text)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = to

    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_string())}

def SendMessageInternal(service, user_id, message):
    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
        print 'Message Id: %s' % message['id']
        return message
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
        return "Error"
    return "OK"

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        to = row['Email']
        sender = "sender"
        subject = "subject"
        dedent_text = '''Hello {}, \n
thank you for your question.'''.format(row['First'])
    message_text = textwrap.dedent(dedent_text).strip()
    SendMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try caching the result of the service call, so that `service` is passed to `SendMessage`. This way, you don't take API call times to setup the API for each individual emails you send.

So at top of your main:

```
def main():
    # Do once
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        to = row['Email']
        sender = "sender"
        subject = "subject"
        dedent_text = '''Hello {}, \n
        thank you for your question.'''.format(row['First'])
        message_text = textwrap.dedent(dedent_text).strip()

        # service is is reused here for each message
        SendMessage(service, sender, to, subject, message_text)
```

Also, if you need to send many messages, make sure you invoke one Python invokation per large batch, since starting up the interpreter and loading many packages can take a while each time.

Comment: Now it runs much faster, thank you.  I am running this from the cmd line. When you say one Python invocation per large batch, do you mean that I should call main() once with all the data I need in the pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')? I thought the modules are cached after they are imported?

Comment: I mean that every time you lunch the python interpreter from the command line, it reloads all modules. If you want email batches to run faster, it's better for your CSV file to contain a larger batch so that you have to relaunch the process with small csv files less often.